# AWS Fargate Sometimes Does not Cleanly Stop MongoDB Container

Tags: mongodb, docker, aws-fargate

I am using the following MongoDB image in an AWS Fargate task definition:
public.ecr.aws/docker/library/mongo:6.0

Sometimes when I stop the task running in the service, I get the following Mongo error upon the task being automatically restarted:
"error": "DBPathInUse: Unable to lock the lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock (Resource temporarily unavailable). Another mongod instance is already running on the /data/db directory"

And then the mongo container automatically terminates. If I restart the service after this it's fine and the mongo instance starts up again. I understand that error the lock file not being properly deleted when the task stops the mongo service running in the container. How would I instruct Fargate to cleanly stop the Mongo container to avoid this when it's stopping a task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Fargate tries to stop a container, it first asks it nicely by sending a `SIGTERM` signal to the container's entry point.

If it doesn't work within a certain time period (set by the parameter [stopTimeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html), 30 seconds by default), it kills the process by sending `SIGKILL` which can't be trapped. Upon receiving this signal, the kernel forcibly terminates all the threads of the process and performs the necessary cleanup (freeing up memory, file descriptors and such like).

The fact that the lock file was left in place means that MongoDB was killed by `SIGKILL` rather than gracefully terminated upon receiving `SIGTERM`. This can happen for various reasons: unresponsive filesystem, buggy `eval` (in earlier versions) etc.

To debug what's happening with the MongoDB instance, you can try stopping it with `SIGUSR2` rather than `SIGTERM`. It will make it put additional trace messages into the log file.

Fargate, unfortunately, doesn't have a way to customize signals used to stop its services, but you can wrap the MongoDB daemon into a shell script, trap `SIGTERM` and convert it to `SIGUSR2` to kill Mongo.

Comment: I appreciate that, very informative.